# Azure Functions: A few http requests throws socket exception

Tags: c#, azure, function, http, sockets

I have a Azure function that is doing HTTP calls to another Azure Function endpoint, both are running in the consumption plan. The HTTP Client is setup via HttpClientFactory. In 99 of 100 times the call gets through successfully, but there are a few requests that throws the SocketException with the error message "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.."

**Stack trace:**

```
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

This is how the client that does the request look like:

```
public class ReadClient : BaseClient, IRClient
{
    private HttpClient Client { get; }

    public ReadClient(IConfiguration config, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) : base(config)
    {
        Client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(ReadClient));
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Get<TResponse>(string url)
    {
        var authenticationToken = GetAuthenticationToken();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authenticationToken.Type, authenticationToken.Token);
        var response = await Client.GetAsync(url);
        return ProccessResponse<TResponse>(response);
    }
}
```

My first thought was that perhaps there were too many requests coming in at the same time and that the function didn't have time to scale up with a new instance, but these occurs randomly at times when there aren't that much traffic. Do you have any idea on how to investigate why these errors occurs?

Comment: I guess, you'll have to put in some more information than that. A little bit of code, for example ...

Comment: @Fildor I added how the client that's responsible for the requests is implemented

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you're not reusing HttpClient properly and it's leading to port exaustion.

This is not an azure function but http client issue and you can read more about it in here:

https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

To solve it when using Azure Functions, please check the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#http-requests

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/errors-diagnostics/sdk-rules/azf0002